# Intercepting URL of MediaPlayerLauncher in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control, windows-phone

I am currently working on a `WebBrowser` control. And when certain video links are clicked, the `MediaPlayerLauncher` automatically opens to play the video. Now if I want to intercept the `MediaPlayerLauncher` and fetch the URL of the mp4 file to do something else with the video (to add to a batch playlist / or maybe download).

How can I achieve this?

I have tried printing the `e.Uri.ToString()` inside the `webBrowser_Navigating()` event, and it isn't called during the `MediaPlayerLauncher` launch.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share that piece of code here